# Positivity of Coulomb energy for gerenal measures

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, mathematical-physics, potential-theory

Suppose $\nu$ is a compactly supported signed measure in $\mathbb R^{n\geq 3}$.

**My question:**

> Is the Coulomb energy still positive?

More precisely 
$$\iint \frac{1}{\|x-y\|^{n-2}}d\nu(x)d\nu(y)\geq 0\ ?$$

Related questions:

1. [Positivity of the Coulomb energy in 2d](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585619/positivity-of-the-coulomb-energy-in-2d)
2. [Positivity of logarithmic energy of certain measures](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202271/positivity-of-logarithmic-energy-of-certain-measures)

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't link1 prove this for at least $\mathbb{R}^3$?  A signed measure will be given by $\nu(A) = \int_A f(x) dx$ where $f$ is $L^1$ when $\nu$ is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue Meausre.  Or do you want this to be true for more general measures?

Comment: The latter.im interested in a mass sitting on a (smooth)surface.so the measure I'm looking at is not A.C to the Lebesgue measure. –  BigM 3 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, at least when the energy of $|\nu|$ is finite, so that the energy of $\nu$ is well defined.  Positivity can be shown via the fourier transform of the Coulomb potential, and by applying Plancherel's Theorem.  See for example Pertti Mattila's "Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension", section 3.5 page 39. You will find that
$$
\iint_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{d\nu(x)d\nu(y)}{|x-y|^{n-2}} = c\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|\widehat{\nu}(k)|^2dk}{|k|^2},
$$
where c is a positive dimensional constant.